# Is there a way to "join" Flutter Widgets with Padding?

Tags: padding, flutter

I have a Row of Flutter widgets that I want to separate with Padding, but only *between* the widgets. Sort of like the behavior for the join() function for Lists, where the String you want to join is only appended between items, not at the end of the List. E.g. For something like this:

```
var square = new Container(height: 50.0, width: 50.0; color: Colors.pink,);
return new Row(
  children: <Widget>[
    square,
    square,
    square,
  ],
);
```

I'll get a row of 3 pink squares with no space between. I want a more programmatic/Flutter built-in way to do this:

```
const _rightPadding = const Padding(padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 16.0));
var square = new Container(height: 50.0, width: 50.0; color: Colors.pink,);
return new Row(
  children: <Widget>[
    square,
    rightPadding,
    square,
    rightPadding,
    square,
    // note there is no padding after this third square
  ],
);
```

I could add a right padding to the `padding` property inside my `square` Widget, but then I'll have extra padding at the end of the Row. I could add an if-statement that checks if I'm the last Widget in the List and not add padding for that one, though it's extra code, and I'm hoping for something more efficient. :)

I notice the [Wrap Widget](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Wrap-class.html) has `runSpacing` and `spacing` properties - this is exactly what I'm looking for, but for Rows and Columns.

Comment: What is the problem of having a Padding widget between each square ?

Comment: It's just extra code; was hoping for a more concise way to do it.

Comment: If you have a custom widget you can add a padding property that defaults to zero if not specified.

Comment: That's a good point!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I searched the docs for `Row` and couldn't find what you are looking for (although it could be there and I just not be able to see it). One way to do this programmatically is to just have a function that takes in a list of elements and return that list with padding in-between but not on the last element. Perhaps something like:

```
List<Widget> createRowChildrenWithPadding(List<Widget> widgets, Padding pading) {
    var joined = List<Widget>();

    for (var i = 0;  i < widgets.length; i++) {
        if ( i != widgets.length - 1)  {
            joined.add(widgets[i]);
            joined.add(padding);
        } else {
            joined.add(widgets[i]);
        }
    }
    return joined;
}
```

Then you can just call this function and pass in the list for your row and assign the return value to the `children` named parameter for the Rows. Let me know if you have any questions, hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks - that's what I'm doing right now. I was hoping for a more concise or built-in way to do it without having to write my own join() function. But maybe it doesn't exist yet.

Comment: you are probably right about that. Sorry I couldn't have been of more help here.

Answer (score 1):

The property you are looking for is `MainAxisAlignment` and the value `MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween` does exactly the job. [Here](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/rendering/MainAxisAlignment-class.html) you find some doc about it.

So, to use such property, you have to fix the width of your row (knowing in advance the number of fixed-size elements you are including). Something like this:

```
var square = new Container(height: 50.0, width: 50.0, color: Colors.pink,);
List<Widget> squareChildren = [square, square, square];
double rowWidth = squareChildren.length*50.0 + (squareChildren.length-1)*16.0;
return new Container(
  width: rowWidth,
  child: new Row(
    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
    children: squareChildren,
  ),
);
```

Comment: True, this works well, if we know the dimensions of the square (in the above example), to calculate the rowWidth.

Answer (score 0):

You could create an extension for that:

```
extension IterableExt<T> on Iterable<T> {
  Iterable<T> superJoin(T separator) {
    final iterator = this.iterator;
    if (!iterator.moveNext()) return [];

    final _l = [iterator.current];
    while (iterator.moveNext()) {
      _l..add(separator)..add(iterator.current);
    }
    return _l;
  }
}
```

And use it like this:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      children: <Widget>[
        const Text('Foo'),
        const Text('Foo'),
        const Text('Bar'),
      ].superJoin(const SizedBox(width: 10,)).toList(),
      
    );
  }
```